# Pass value in Axios without parameter name in a React Native app

Tags: react-native

```
const getRating = () => {
  axios
    .post('https://example.com/api/engage.php', {
    "eyJnaWQiOiIxMjg5MTA3NjQifQ==",
    },{
headers:{
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'api-token': 'Zk4gcwJFovIpPaXtgyA55l0BSi8ETAxfAntuq7zp1L-x4OP27G-9UtaChlNExufQ4msa38aHDNQdQQ',
}
}     
).then(function (response) {
      // handle success
      alert(JSON.stringify(response.data));
     
      
    }).catch(function (error) {
      // handle error
      alert(error.message);
    });
};
```

I want to pass encoded string value with the above API and the value doesn't have name. I have tried the same in Postman, and it's working. But how to achieve the same in React Native?

Comment: Which error status is raised at this API call?

Comment: Unexpected token (40:36)

  38 |     axios
  39 |       .post('https://startup.indiafilings.com/api/engagement-rating.php', {
> 40 |       "eyJnaWQiOiIxMjg5MTA3NjQifQ==",
     |                                     ^
  41 |       },{

Comment: Could you please test this: 
axios
    .post(
        "http://localhost:4000/api/token", 
        "mytoken", 
        {headers: {"Content-Type": "text/plain"}}
    )
    .then(r => console.log(r.status))
    .catch(e => console.log(e));

Comment: it's saying unexpected token on the line where i am passing value

Comment: Actually use your token {
    "eyJnaWQiOiIxMjg5MTA3NjQifQ==",
    } without ```{}``` .

Comment: ok i will try and update

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.